# Trouble merging objects

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, texturing, eevee-render-engine

I am trying to model a smart phone, but I faced this light problem.

As u can see from the photo the light is destroying the object its look like there is two objects.

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this problem? I tried a Shrinkwrap modifier but didin't work :(

.blend file if needed [image]

Comment: Please share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on that page to add the link to your question.

Comment: If you're using two models, then the upper model have to copy the surface normal infos from the lower surface.

To transfer the normal infos you have to use the Data Transfer Modifier->Face Corner Data->Custom Normals

You shold also define a vertex group to limit this effect to the lower border edge.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works.

Best wishes

Chris

Here's your modified file:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks man, but why the edges still noticeably?. is there any way I can merge them more so they be like one object??

Comment: I guees there are not enough subdivisions in your Phone model. The normals are calculated on a interpolated basis. The best will be to connect the case by modeling it.

Answer (score 0):

Here I've booled the mesh in and joined both meshes then. Cleaned up some vertex. 5 mins work.

Here's the file:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wooo, man your work is amazing

Comment: Please vote my post up, if you think it helps you or solve your problem. This help others, who have the same issue. Thanx